# First steps on Assembly - LED changing

Tags: assembly

Below iam writing the code of a programm on assembly language as referenced by a book i have.
It says that on a terminal PTD4 we have connected a LED. The programm kepps the led "on" for 1 second and "off" for 1 second. The situation keeps going forever. If you know what should i change below in order to have the LED on two different phases. Particularly I want it to be ON for 5 senconds and off for 6 seconds.
Thanks in advance. Here is the code.

```
PORTD.DATA        EQU   $0003
PORTD.DIRECTION   EQU   $0007
COUNTER1          EQU   $0040
COUNTER2          EQU   $0041
COUNTER3          EQU   $0042
ROM.START         EQU   $8000
RESET.VECTOR      EQU   $FFFE

                  ORG   ROM.START
                  BSET  0,$001F
                  MOV   #$1F,$003C

                  BSET  4,PORTD.DIRECTION

LOOP              BSET  4,PORTD.DATA
                  JSR   DELAY.1SEC
                  BCLR  4,PORTD.DATA
                  JSR   DELAY.1SEC
                  JMP   LOOP

DELAY.1SEC        MOV   #!55,COUNTER3
LOAD.COUNTER2     MOV   #!100,COUNTER2
LOAD.COUNTER1     MOV   #!180,COUNTER1

DELAY.LOOP        DBNZ  COUNTER1,DELAY.LOOP
                  DBNZ  COUNTER2,LOAD.COUNTER1
                  DBNZ  COUNTER3,LOAD.COUNTER2

                  RTS

                  ORG   RESET.VECTOR
                  FDB   ROM.START
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, durations of on and off are 1 second which is coded as

```
JSR   DELAY.1SEC
```

To modify the code to "ON for 5 seconds and off for 6 seconds", you need two subroutines which wait 5 seconds and 6 seconds respectively.

An example of "wait for 5 seconds" subroutine may be ( I assume that a counter named 'COUNTER4' is available on the processor)

```
DELAY.5SEC     MOV #!5,COUNTER4
DELAY5.LOOP    JSR DELAY.1SEC
               DBNZ COUNTER4,DELAY5.LOOP
               RTS
```

"wait for 6 seconds" subroutine is simular to DELAY.5SEC but it set 6 to COUNTER4 at begining.

Then loop part of your code shoule be modified as

```
LOOP          BSET  4,PORTD.DATA
              JSR   DELAY.5SEC
              BCLR  4,PORTD.DATA
              JSR   DELAY.6SEC
              JMP   LOOP
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help. Please tell me if iam wrong. I will right it as an answera above. :)